# Ajax loader image: How to set a minimum duration during which the loader is shown?

Tags: ajax, user-interface, jquery

I am using Jquery for Ajax functionality, and using a loader icon to indicate to the user that data is being retrieved. However, I want the user to see the loader icon for at least 1s, even if the data takes less than 1s to retrieve (if more than 1s is required, the loader icon should remain for the entire duration.

Here is the code for the loader HTML

`<img id="loader" src="example.com/images/
loader.gif" style="vertical-align: middle; display: none" />`

I am using the Jquery .Ajax function for my data processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a counter that starts at 2 and is decremented after 1 second and when the ajax response comes in. Something along these lines:

```
var counter = 2;
function decrement() {
  if (--counter == 0) {
    $('#loader').hide();
  }
}
setTimeout(decrement, 1000);
$.ajax(..., complete: decrement);
```

Comment: this will not work my friend. This will allow the loader to be shown for a maximum of 2 seconds, while in production the loader should not appear until the ajax response completes. The only thing this code does is insure a minimum loader display time of 1s. However, the maximum time should be equal to however long the ajax request will take! Thanks for the input/effort, though!

Comment: @whamsicore why won't it work? I'm pretty sure it will. setTimeout only fires once--you might be thinking of setInterval, which fires over and over again. So this approach will do what was requested: show the loader until the ajax request completes, but not less than 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

First, show the loader image. Then use `setTimeout()` to to start a timer. When the timer is finished, check if the AJAX has finished, if it has then kill the loader image but if it hasn't then do nothing to the loader image and set a flag. When the AJAX success handler is called, check the flag; if the flag is set then the timer has finished and the success handler can delete the loader image; if the flag is not set, then the success handler can let the timer kill the loader image.

Essentially, you have two asynchronous tasks running (the timeout and the AJAX). The last one to finish kills the loader image.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. See it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/B4Cge/

```
var loader = '<img id="loader" src="http://tools.patentcalls.com/images/spinner.gif"/>';

    $(loader).appendTo('#container').load(function() {
        $('#container').find('#loader').delay(3000).fadeOut(function() {
            $('#container').append('your ajax content')
        })
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works a little bit? doesn't the .load require some kind of URL to pass data to? (remember, the loaders purpose is to pass data, and retrieve a response, sorry if that wasn't clear in the beginning). Thanks for the input btw.

Comment: @whamsicore There are 2 types of loads in jQuery, see http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=load. We are using load event and not the loading of a file. You can read more about the load event here http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. In this example, everything in between the load function will only load after image has been appended to container. then ajax or whatever callback method you choose will only load after fadeout is complete.