# jQuery ajax loading - display the loading image for a min. of 1 second

Tags: jquery, ajax, timer, loading

i have a jquery ajax request.
On page load a loading-image is displayed.
this is working well, but i want to display the loading gif for a minimum of 1 second.

I've already tried this: [Ajax loader image: How to set a minimum duration during which the loader is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025839/ajax-loader-image-how-to-set-a-minimum-duration-during-which-the-loader-is-show) ,
but it's not working.

My code is:

```
<div id="ajaxcontent"><img src="loader.gif" id="ajaxloading" /></div>
```

and

```
$.ajax({
// some code for the request
success: function () {
             $('#ajaxcontent').text(myResultText);
        }
```

I've also tried to add .delay(1000) before the text is shown, but this also does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this ?

```
   setTimeout(function() { $('#ajaxcontent').text(myResultText);},
               1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `delay()` method in jQuery relates to animations, so it won't delay the updating of any properties of an element. Instead, try using the `setTimeout()` function, which runs the code you specify after waiting for a set number of miliseconds:

```
$.ajax({
    // some code for the request
    success: function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#ajaxcontent').text(myResultText);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```