# How do I set the minimum duration of an Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I have a website that makes an ajax call and then loads a gif to show static on a TV. But right now the ajax calls don't take enough time for the effect to really pop. So I was wondering if there is a way to set the minimum time the ajax call will take?

You can see [the website](http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/test/demo.html) I am trying to make to get a better idea of what I am doing. Try clicking the right picture frame or the phonograph on the table.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var minDelay = 1000;
    var start = new Date();
    $.get("form.html", function(result) {
        callback($(result).find("#contact"));
        var end = new Date();
        var timeInMilliseconds = end - start;
        if (timeInMilliseconds  < minDelay) {
            setTimeout(function() { callback(result); }, minDelay - timeInMilliseconds );
        }
        else callback(result);
    });
    $.get("music.html", function(result) {
        callback($(result).find("#music"));
        var end = new Date();
        var timeInMilliseconds = end - start;
        if (timeInMilliseconds  < minDelay) {
            setTimeout(function() { callback(result); }, minDelay - timeInMilliseconds );
        }
        else callback(result);
    });


    function callback(result) {
        $("#screen").html(result);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can time the start and end points, and then add another delay if it's below a certain threshold (using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)).  Something like this:

```
var minDelay = 1000;
var start = new Date();
$.get(url, function(result) {
    var end = new Date();
    var timeInMilliseconds = end - start;
    if (timeInMilliseconds  < minDelay) {
        setTimeout(function() { callback(result); }, minDelay - timeInMilliseconds });
    }
    else callback(result);
});

function callback(result) {
    // Ajax response handling here ...
}
```

---

**Edit** I'm not sure you can achieve this using JQuery's `load` (per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/), the target gets updated immediately after the response is received from the server).  I'd suggest converting the `load` calls into `gets`.  Ie, this:

```
$("#screen").load("form.html #contact");
```

Should become this:

```
$.get("form.html", function(result) {
    callback($(result).find("#contact"));
});
```

And the `callback` function I made up above should then populate the target of `load`.

```
 function callback(html) {
     $("#screen").html(html);
 }
```

Comment: can you elaborate with the code I have added to my post? i am using the jquery .load function. is this a problem? thanks dbaseman

Comment: @katiebekell hm, yes, per the docs, I don't see how you could achieve this using `load`... can you switch those out for `get` calls?

Comment: where do i set what gif should be called and I also noticed that you changed function(result) to response(result) should it be response? thanks for the help I can see the light

Comment: I changed things to the way you suggested and for some reason it is no longer working - i will post my new code in my question

Comment: @katiebekell sorry, should be `function(result)`, not response(result).  That was a typo.

Comment: yea that works now but for some reason the form.html page isnt being found - i also couldn't find a way to use .get('url #div') am I missing something?

Comment: @katiebekell Strange that it works for `load` but not for `get`.  No prob though, you should be able to get the page and then find the specific element.  See above.

Comment: I guess that's another feature specific to `load`.  You can get the same effect by using `$(response).find("#div")` on the `$.get` result though.

Comment: that fixed the error of the page not being found but now i am getting a new error in firebug that says teh following:"TypeError: "#screen".html is not a function" from this line of code: ("#screen").html(result); any idea why that is happening? thanks again sorry this is turning into such a hassle

Comment: @katiebekell ha, wow, sorry, I am a typo machine.  That should be a JQuery selector with a dollar sign: `$("#screen").html(result)`.

Comment: nice that worked but now the page is loading the ajax call automatically instead of showing the home page (the page with the frames and the room) i think it is because of how i am calling the ajax. i have updated my code in my post - i think it is because i am calling multiple gets() :/ thanks for your help

Comment: @katiebekell well, you need to put the Ajax calls inside a click event handler or something, don't you?

Comment: oh man yea sorry that was really foolish - i have one last question then i will give you the big check for correct - where do i put the gif that will display while ajax is executing

Comment: @katiebekell yay, checks.  Um, I guess you'd add the gif before making the Ajax call, something like `$("#screen").html("<img src='thegif.gif' />")`

Comment: for some reason the two ajax calls are moving at different speeds and the loading gif isnt working properly but i appreciate your help and you got me going in the right direction so thanks again - i might ask for some more help but for now i will try and figure things out

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `setTimeout()` method in the ajax callback method to simulate a delay?
Pretty cool website btw!

Sample code:

```
var minDelay = 500;//half a second
setTimeout(DelayTimePassed, minDelay);
//make Ajax Call

function DelayTimePassed()
{
if(dataAvailable)
//show Data
else
//show data as soon as available
}

function AjaxCallback()
{
if(showDataAsSoonAsAvailable)
//Show Data Now
else
dataAvailable=true;//show data after time delay passes
}
```

Hope that makes sense to you - two methods check a couple of global bool variables to decide when to show the data.

Comment: can you show me where the setTimeout() would go? I tried this and couldn't get the results I was hoping for  thanks Im glad you like the site

Comment: im sorry but I am still a bit lost - i have added my ajax code to my post. i am just using the load() function

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with jQuery, but I found another question that touches upon this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025839/ajax-loader-image-how-to-set-a-minimum-duration-during-which-the-loader-is-show

Apparently your ajax call has to be a little different, since the .load method automatically closes static-on-tv when it gets a response.