# convert my jquery .load to .ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have a .load() function that I need to convert to .ajax(). I initially used .load() because of its ease of use but now I see that in order to achieve my desired result, I must use .ajax().
Here is my .load() function:

```
$("#rightframe").click(function(){
    $("#screen").load("form.html #contact");
  });
```

I want to convert that to .ajax() and add the following piece of code to set a minimum time an .ajax() call would take (this is because I have a loading GIF that looks weird if it doesn't run long enough)

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025839/ajax-loader-image-how-to-set-a-minimum-duration-during-which-the-loader-is-show) piece of code when trying to figure out how I can set a minimum length of time the loading GIF would take.

```
var counter = 2;
function decrement() {
  if (--counter == 0) {
    $('#loader').hide();
  }
}
setTimeout(decrement, 1000);
$.ajax(..., complete: decrement);
```

Does anyone know how to alter the .load() function to .ajax() and add the decrement function to the .ajax() function?

Thank you,

Katie

Comment: Part about decrement is not clear.

Comment: sorry for the confusion I have elaborated a bit - thank you for your quick response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd want something like this:

```
$("#rightframe").click(function () {
    $("#loader").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "form.html",
            complete: function () {
                $("#loader").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#screen").empty().append($(data).find("#contact"));
            },
            error: function () {
                // Handle an error occurring
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

I'm not sure why you are using/need the `decrement` function, but something like this code should take care of the loading image being shown long enough.

Comment: yea I think this is perfect - I found the decrement code while searching for a solution to my problem. I will give it a shot thanks a lot ianpgall

Comment: @katiebekell No problem! Yeah, I try to stay away from `.load`, `.post`, `.get`, and the likes, because there's a lot of things assumed. I just like to use `.ajax` because I customize it almost completely to do exactly what I need. I've seen the syntax `.load("form.html #contact")` but was never sure what the "#contact" meant - I'm assuming it only grabs the element with the `id` "contact" from the response in `data` and loads that into "#screen". Is that right? If so, that's what I put in the `success` function to do.

Comment: hey ianpgall for some reason the code you have given me doesn't load the form into the div but it is certainly working perfectly other wise
do you think you could check out the [site](http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/test/demo.html) and tell me what you think is happening? just click on the right picture frame thanks!

Comment: @katiebekell Hmm It seems to work for me (unless I'm misunderstanding what **should** happen). When I click on the right picture frame, it shows the fuzzy image for 2 seconds, then displays a contact form. Is that wrong? The left picture frame doesn't work though

Comment: i just got rid of the #contact and it works perfect thanks a lot

Comment: i would still like to know if there is a way to grab the div tho any help would be much appreciated

Comment: @katiebekell Hmm I'm not sure what the problem would be. I would expect it to work as I provided (with the way `.find` works). What happened when you included the `.find` call? What is returned in `data`?

Comment: @Ian I'm pretty sure you're missing the trailing `)` from line 2 after `$("#loader"`. Correct me if I'm wrong. It's a nuance and obviously those using this code would correct that when writing it themselves, but just thought I'd bring it up.